# Network 500 errors with mvc routing when I add multiple parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am trying to implement some routing for a blog I want the url to be displayed with mutiple parameters but It I keep getting loads of 500 network errors and it seems that it starts looking for jquery and images in different places when i get the desired route I want.

Heres the route

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
    "Events",
    "Post/{action}/{id}/{categoryName}/{blogTitle}",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "Detail", id = "", 
          categoryName = "", blogTitle = "" }
);
```

heres the controller

```
public ActionResult Details(int id, string categoryName, string blogTitle)
{
    SitePosts posts = new SitePosts();
    Post post = posts.GetPost(id);

    ViewBag.IsAdmin = IsAdmin;
    return View(post);
}
```

and here is the link I am using in a cshtml razor helper

```
<a href="@Href("~/Post/Details/" + post.ID + "/" + post.Category.CategoryName + "/" + post.Title)">
```

same thing applies if i do a redirect to action
return RedirectToAction("Details", "Post", new { id = uid, categoryName = post.Category.CategoryName, blogTitle = UrlEncoder.ToFriendlyUrl(post.Title) });

please I have no idea why this is happening
I have a screen print of lots of http get errors regarding trying to find javascript and images
at post/details/content/jquery etc etc but It will not let me post

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Html ActionLink helper instead of creating it yourself.  Also, you can adjust your routing table and omit the values that you are passing, you do not need to declare those in your route with the = "" syntax, just leave them in the route expression.

**Route Table**

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
    "Events",
    "Post/Detail/{id}/{categoryName}/{blogTitle}",
    new { controller = "Post", action = "Detail" }
);
```

**View - Create a Link**

```
    @Html.ActionLink("DisplayText", "Detail", new{controller="Post", id = post.ID,
 categoryName=post.Category.CategoryName, blogTitle = post.Title})
```